# Internet doesn't work when running windows phone 8 emulator

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have installed Visual Studio 2013  which comes with Windows Phone 8 Emulator. When I am trying to run emulator my internet in both laptop and emulator doesn't work. Earlier it was working in my laptop. I checked in network connections its creating a "Bridge". I am not sure what is the issue. Internet in my laptop works only if i remove "Bridged Connection".

My friend use to share internet using Connectify Hotspot and i used to connect for internet access. I am not sure if that is the problem.

Comment: Does the Connectify Hotspot have a specific number of devices that it can have tethered to it?

Comment: I am not sure if it has any limit. But I am the only one connecting to  internet but it works fine even with 3-4 devices are connected to it.